# How do I integrate this function?

Tags: numerical-integration

I am very new to mathematica and also new to this community.
I have a problem given below, How to express this in Mathematica?

$H=[2,4,10,5,12,34,42,\cdots 12]$ is a vector of size $N$. $h_n$ is the $n$th element of $H$. For example, $h_3=10$ and $h_N=12$.

$F(\theta)=h_{N/2+1}+2\sum_{l=1}^{N/2-1}h_{N/2-l}\cos (\theta l)$

I want to calculate $\int_{.234}^{432}(F(\theta))^2$

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 
1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 
2) Read the [faq]!
3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge.
Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Answer (score 1):

is this what you are looking for?

```
h = {2, 4, 10, 5, 12, 34, 12, 11};
n = Length[h];
f[x_?NumericQ] := h[[n/2 + 1]] + 2 NSum[ h[[n/2 - i]] Cos[x*i], {i, 1, n/2 - 1}]

NIntegrate[f[x]^2, {x, 0.234, 0.432}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 1):

```
h = {5, 7, 8, 15, 11, 17, 20, 20, 5, 3}; (*put your vector here*)
n = Length[h] ;(*length of the vector, Even number*)
F[x_] = h[[n/2 + 1]] + 2 Sum[h[[n/2 - l]] Cos[x l], {l, 1, n/2 - 1}];
NIntegrate[F[x]^2, {x, 0.234, 0.432}]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
func[t_, v_] := With[{s = Length[v]/2},
  2 Total@MapIndexed[#1 Cos[First@#2 t] &, Reverse[v[[1 ;; s - 1]]]] +
    v[[s + 1]]]
```

Test:

```
h = {2, 4, 10, 5, 12, 34, 12, 11};
Integrate[func[t, h]^2, {t, 0.234, 0.432}]
```

yields: 305.526

Adjust as desired for non-even list length